Tried the package & namespace - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
Instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, which packages we can use in .NET 8.0 ?
I tried the packages & namespaces Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.
But I am still getting an error

Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'


Update your Program.cs or Startup.cs to add Newtonsoft.Json support
builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new 
    CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
});


In my project Program.cs contains following,

Please, where to add your code in my Pro.cs,
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
var sharedFolder = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "..", "Shared");
.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(sharedFolder, "SharedSettings.json"), optional: true)
config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
}).UseStartup().Build();

Where to add your code in my startup.cs,
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
baseConfigureServices(services, "Gold Loans API", "v1");
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
baseConfigure(app, env, "API");
}

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
